# How do I evaluate this series? $\sum_{i=1}^{m-6}(i+2)\binom{2i-1}{i}\frac{1}{m-2-i}\binom{2m-2i+6}{m-i+3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients

I'm working on a study about nonlinear reccurence.

$a_1 = 1, a_2 = 3, a_3 = 12, a_4 = 50, a_5 = 210$

I'm trying to find the general term of $a_m$ and I found that it follows the recurrence

$a_{m+1}=\sum_{i=1}^{m-6}a_{i+1}\frac{1}{m-2-i}\binom{2m-2i+6}{m-i+3}+\frac{1}{m+1}\binom{2m}{m}+\binom{2m+1}{m+1}$

I guess that $a_{m+1}=(m+2)\binom{2m-1}{m}$

I'm thinking of using mathematical induction to prove it, but I don't know how to evaluate the series.

$\sum_{i=1}^{m-6}(i+2)\binom{2i-1}{i}\frac{1}{m-2-i}\binom{2m-2i+6}{m-i+3}$

What can I do to solve the problem?

Comment: What is the problem asking for? To find a general term $a_m$? There are infinitely many expressions that works if this is the problem.

Comment: Why would you believe that thing is summable?

Comment: I can't tell if this is summable. How do you determine a summable series?

Comment: There's no one set technique for it. There's lots of things you can try depending on the form of the series. None that I know work on stuff like this.

Comment: Did you consider the difference $a_{m+1}-a_m$ sequence? I tried and gave up.

Comment: I haven't tried the difference $a_{m+1}-a_m$ sequence yet. But I think it wouldn't be easy to do that since the summation has different coefficient for different $a_i$.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a typo in your recursion equation, but the correct solution seems to be $$a_{m+1}=2 \left({}^{2m-6}C_{m-3} \right)$$

But this solution does not satisfy your constraints.

Comment: I think it's my fault. There is a typo in the recursion equation. I've fixed it.